# To print a Tic Tac Toe table, which code is better?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a part of a game TicTacToe. Both of them print a table of Tic Tac Toe, same output, but which one is better in algorithm and code quality? Is there anything can be modify to make it better?

```
#self.board is a list contains value of this table.
# e.g. an empty board should look like this:
#    0   1   2
# 0    |   |
#   -----------
# 1    |   |
#   -----------
# 2    |   |


# code 1
    printFormat = "\n   0   1   2 \n0  {} | {} | {} \n   -----------\n1  {} | {} | {} \n   -----------\n2  {} | {} | {} "
    print(printFormat.format(*self.board[0],*self.board[1],*self.board[2]))

# code 2
    printList = []
    txtFormat ="{:} {:^3}"+"|{:^3}"*(self.size-1)
    titleFormat = "{:^3} " * self.size
    numbers = range(self.size)
    line1 = "\n   "+titleFormat.format(*numbers)
    printList.append(line1)

    for i in range(self.size):
        contentLine = txtFormat.format(numbers[i],*self.board[i])
        printList.append(contentLine)
        cutOffLine = "   "+"-"*(4*self.size-1)
        printList.append(cutOffLine)

    printList.pop()
    for item in printList:
        print(item)
```

Comment: This question looks off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you have working code and are asking for code review, there is a StackExchange site for that: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: They are both equally unreadable in my opinion. At least #2 is easily expandable to use the actual crosses and O's.